# Golang - GoMobile tool for cross platform slices of struct return type

Tags: go, cross-platform, gomobile

During the journey of cross-platform mobile app development, I came across Golang which is having a GoMobile command line tool which generates language bindings that make it possible to call Go functions from Java and Objective-C. However, there are some restriction on the types used in an exported function/method as documented here: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind#hdr-Type_restrictions

So any idea about the work in progress to support slices of struct (Array of struct) in the data types used in exported functions

Comment: My guess is you are best off to use a kind of serialize/deserialize step at the boundary.

Comment: @RickyA Thanks. True that's the last option I have if there is no inbuilt support coming soon.

Comment: Here is the gomobile project issue about this feature: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13445

Answer (score 1):

A workaround with `String` as an example:

```
type StringCollection interface {
    Add(s string) StringCollection
    Get(i int) string
    Size() int
}

// TODO solve this with generics
type StringArray struct {
    items []string
}

func (array StringArray) Add(s string) StringArray {
    array.items = append(array.items, s)
    return array
}

func (array StringArray) Get(i int) string {
    return array.items[i]
}

func (array StringArray) Size() int {
    return len(array.items)
}
```

Usage in go:

```
func GetExampleStringArray() *StringArray {
    strings := []string{"example1", "example2"}
    return &StringArray{items: strings}
}
```

On Android you can use this extension to convert it to a `List<String>`:

```
fun StringArray.toStringList(): List<String> {
    val list = mutableListOf<String>()
    for (i in 0 until size()) {
        list.add(get(i))
    }
    return list
}

fun main() {
    GoPackage.getExampleStringArray().toStringList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think currently nobody works on gomobile slice interface implementation.
You might want to check this convenience project.

https://github.com/scisci/go-mobile-collection

and here is a simple example how you can share slice outside without any projects:

```
type MyType struct {
        Id       int64
        Name     string
}

var (
        items []MyType
)

func GetItemsCount() int {
        return len(items)
}

func GetItem(i int) *MyItem {
        if i >= 0 && i < len(items) {
                return &items[i]
        }
        return nil
}
```

In case of threads I'm usually adding mutex in code.

We sharing our business logic (everything what we can move out from mobile native code) and it works perfect.
Using `gomobile 1.13` in `bind` mode. Only one WORKING solution for iOS/Android effective crossplatform development. React is good but takes more space.
Really like Swift, but ~40mb lib deps in mobile app kills it. Using it in our apps: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonje and upcoming iOS release: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lonje-anonymous-chat-video/id1215525783